# Invoke applet methods from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, applet

I'm using an applet that I didn't developed. I want to simulate a click on a button. I'm pretty sure that the method that I need it's called getHtml(), but it's not in the applet class...
So, the applet is on pt.dgci.taxClient.v2013.iva.app.IVAApplet.class and the method that I think I need is on pt.dgci.taxClient.v2013.iva.ui.IVAHtml.class.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ricardoorfao/WNZX7/

Theoretically it should be something like

- HTML

  ```html
  <applet id="printIvaApplet" codebase="https://www.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/pf/java/" archive="DPIVA-UI-v2013-3.2.12.0058-applet.jar" code="pt.dgci.taxClient.v2013.iva.ui.IVAHtml.class" name="PrtIVA" width="0" height="0" align="middle" title="teste"></applet>
  ```
- Javascript

  ```javascript
  var html = document.PrtIVA.getHtml();
  ```

Basically I want to simulate a user's click interaction, like where says "Imprimir". Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: So.. you want to hot-link to the Portuguese Financial Portal in a 0x0 applet then interact with the applet using JS?  I can see there might be some security concerns that get in the way of successfully achieving that goal.

Comment: Yes, something like that. I know that in 2003 was possible to do that, to print the content of the applet. It was applet_name.getHtml(); but now I'm thinking that is not possible. I can access to the public methods of the applet (like getData()). I found this http://www.sitepoint.com/connect-java-to-javascript-with-liveconnect/ and I'm trying to understand how to use it. Maybe it's the solution.